# jEdit: using SuperAbbrevs within SuperAbbrevs

Tags: jedit

I just discovered the very useful [SuperAbbrevs](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?SuperAbbrevs) plugin for jEdit. I've programmed a few abbreviations and it works great. But I like to do the following.

Abbreviations:

`p = <p>${1:}</p>`

`img = <img src="${1:}" alt="${2:}" />`

So when I type:

`p` it will give me an empty `<p></p>` and place the cursor in the middle. I then type `img` in the middle of the `p` tag and hit `TAB` to active the next SuperAbbrev (triggering the `img` tag). However, instead of also converting this into my full text, it will just just to the end of the abbreviation and I end up with: 
`<p>img</p>`

When I manually go back and hit `TAB` after the `img` text it WILL work, but I need to leave the `p` tag first and that defeats the purpose of the abbreviations. Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Set this in the template:

`<p>$end</p>`

That way, the cursor jumps to the center and the abbreviation ends, allowing other abbreviations to be entered right away.